# What is the F1 Score for my prediction when all values are negative?

Tags: python, accuracy, f1

I have built a model that gives me classification of some cases

here is a comparison between Actual and Prediction

```
Prediction   Actual
------------------------
    0          0
    0          0
    0          0
    0          0
    0          0
    0          0
    0          0
    0          0
    0          0
```

They all match and they all negative

when I try to get F1 Score for this case I get divided by zero

which makes sense as the Precision is TP / TP+FP (which all are zeros)

so in my case what would the F1 score be?

Comment: I think the existing answers to this question are a bit shortsighted. No, the F1 score cannot be calculated, but what is the “spirit” of what it “should” be? For instance, $\sin(x)/x$ is undefined at zero, yet we can make sense of the limit as $x$ approaches zero. Is there something similar? I feel this is a common enough situation and F1 a common enough measure of performance (despite its [issues](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603663/academic-reference-on-the-drawbacks-of-accuracy-f1-score-sensitivity-and-or-sp)) to warrant a more detailed response than “can’t divide by zero”.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you cannot calculate F1-score.
You cannot also calculate precision and recall score.
Use accuracy instead of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already answered your question: Divided by Zero.
F1-score is calculated from Precision and Recall. Your example only contains negative case. So you can't calculate positive related items(Precision). In human words: You don't have enough data to evaluate this model.